# How to post XQuery code to MarkLogic using cURL from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, curl, xquery, marklogic

I am using Ubuntu machine.
I am doing POST call using curl command and sending **xquery code** as --data in string format.
In response I am getting below error:

```
xdmp:database()HTTP/1.1 500 REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM: (rest:UNSUPPORTEDPARAM) Endpoint does not support query parameter: xdmp:database()
```

Below is the complete **curl command**

```
curl -v --digest -u username --request POST "http://host:port/qconsole/endpoints/evaler.xqy?dbid=someid&querytype=xquery&action=eval" --data "xdmp:database()"
```

In the above command Basically I am trying to run xquery code on the targeted machine (host:port/endpoints/evaler.xqy)

Is this the right way to pass xquery code?

**Update:**

I am using **ML 7**

After passing the headers I am able to run the XQuery code but facing one more issue.

When I am passing "xdmp:database()" as data It's working fine (see the below command), in the response I am getting database ID.

```
 curl -v --digest -uusername --data "xdmp:database()" --header "Content-type:text/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" --request POST "http://host:port/qconsole/endpoints/evaler.xqy?dbid=dbid&querytype=xquery&action=eval"
```

When I tried with passing "let $x := 10 return $x" as data (As given in below command) I am getting

**x: undefined variable**

even not asking for password!!

```
 curl -v --digest -u username --data "let $x := 10 return $x" --header "Content-type:text/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" --request POST "http://host:port/qconsole/endpoints/evaler.xqy?dbid=dbid&querytype=xquery&action=eval"
```

Not able to figure it out, What I am doing wrong.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some [example bash](https://gist.github.com/jmakeig/1913f50def91f4c5f7f1802cee7a6b81) that uses cURL to eval JavaScript from stdin. (Changing to XQuery is just a matter of changing the parameter name.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Pipes stdin as the JavaScript body of a REST Client API eval request
#
# Usage:
#   cat cat mycode.js | awk … | curl … @-
#   pbpaste | awk … | curl … @-

awk '{print "javascript="$0}' | curl http://localhost:8000/v1/eval --digest -u "$USER":"$PASS" -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: multipart/mixed' -d @-
```

You’ll need to set up your `$USER` and `$PASS` variables appropriately.

Comment: As others have noted, `/v1/eval` was introduced in MarkLogic 8. This is one of the many good reasons to upgrade if you’re still running MarkLogic 7.

Comment: Yes I am using ML 7, I can't change to ML 8 because of some critical reasons!
please help me for ML 7

Answer (score 2):

I think you are better off using the REST endpoint for evaluation:

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/eval

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

If using MarkLogic 8+, then you should use /v1/eval, as @grtjn noted. Since you used the marklogic-7 tag, it looks like you're on ML7.

The top choice, regardless of version, would be to create a [REST API extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions) for whatever this code is supposed to do, assuming you're not trying to support arbitrary XQuery execution. If you are, you could create an extension that mimics what /v1/eval does. Better yet, upgrade to ML8 if you can and use /v1/eval itself.